# When using the Django model library, what is the syntax for creating "or" statements in filters?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for the correct syntax for:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(propertyA = 'foo' OR propertyB = 'bar')
```

What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

It would be :

```
from django.db.models import Q
SomeModel.objects.filter(Q(propertyA=foo) | Q(propertyB=bar))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

SomeModel.objects.filter(Q(propertyA='foo') | Q(propertyB='bar'))
```